# Foursquare Push Notification

Tags: api, notifications, push, foursquare

I am trying to find the API push feature in Foursquare that will push a third party notification to a user when they enter a venue.  For example, when a Foursquare user enters a location and checks in, a notification from the venue saying 2 for 1 beer special tonight ...OR...an offer from a pizza place down the street is pushed into the Foursquare app.

Can a third party (Pizza Place) activate a push notification for that venue when a consumer checks in...or....can only the venue allow notifications when someone checks in and the pizza place will need to partner with the venue to get the notification pushed to the user?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To receive a realtime update that a user has checked into a venue, you need to either have the user authorize the app, or to have the manager of the venue authorize the app.

See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime for more details.